# Download image with url but it doesn't show in galery

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, download, imagedownload

I'm using the code from the example of this dependencie image_downloader: ^0.31.0, the problem is that it doesn't show any error but the image doesn't go to the galery.
This screen is to show the images from firestore and create listtyle that when the user clicks the image is suposed to download it.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_downloader/image_downloader.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pap_test/upload/upload_resumos_screen.dart';

class DownloadScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DownloadScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = '/downlaod-resumos';

  @override
  State<DownloadScreen> createState() => _DownloadScreenState();
}

class _DownloadScreenState extends State<DownloadScreen> {
  String _message = "";
  String _path = "";
  String _size = "";
  String _mimeType = "";
  File? _imageFile;
  int _progress = 0;
  String query = '1';

  CollectionReference _firebaseFirestore =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('images');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Resumos'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _firebaseFirestore.snapshots().asBroadcastStream(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            if (snapshot.data!.docs
                .where((QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>
                        element) =>
                    element['disciplina']
                        
                        .toString()
                        .toLowerCase()
                        
                        .contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                .isEmpty) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Por aqui está muito lento, carrega no botão e publica um resumo.',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView(
                children: [
                  
                  ...snapshot.data!.docs
                      .where((QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>
                              element) => 
                          element['disciplina']
                              
                              .toString()
                              .toLowerCase()
                              
                              .contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                      .map(
                    (QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?> data) {
                      
                      final String descricao = data.get('descricao');
                      
                      final _image = data['url'];
                      
                      return ListTile(
                        onTap: () {
                          _downloadImage(_image);
                          
                        },
                        
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_image),
                        ),

                       
                        title: Text(
                          descricao.toString(),
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _downloadImage(
    String url, {
    AndroidDestinationType? destination,
    bool whenError = false,
    String? outputMimeType,
  }) async {
    String? fileName;
    String? path;
    int? size;
    String? mimeType;
    try {
      String? imageId;

      if (whenError) {
        imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url,
                outputMimeType: outputMimeType)
            .catchError((error) {
          if (error is PlatformException) {
            String? path = "";
            if (error.code == "404") {
              print("Not Found Error.");
            } else if (error.code == "unsupported_file") {
              print("UnSupported FIle Error.");
              path = error.details["unsupported_file_path"];
            }
            setState(() {
              _message = error.toString();
              _path = path ?? '';
            });
          }

          print(error);
        }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () {
          print("timeout");
          return;
        });
      } else {
        if (destination == null) {
          imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(
            url,
            outputMimeType: outputMimeType,
          );
        } else {
          imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(
            url,
            destination: destination,
            outputMimeType: outputMimeType,
          );
        }
      }

      if (imageId == null) {
        return;
      }
      fileName = await ImageDownloader.findName(imageId);
      path = await ImageDownloader.findPath(imageId);
      size = await ImageDownloader.findByteSize(imageId);
      mimeType = await ImageDownloader.findMimeType(imageId);
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      setState(() {
        _message = error.message ?? '';
      });
      return;
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(
      () {
        var location = Platform.isAndroid ? "Directory" : "Photo Library";
        _message = 'Saved as "$fileName" in $location.\n';
        _size = 'size:     $size';
        _mimeType = 'mimeType: $mimeType';
        _path = path ?? '';

        if (!_mimeType.contains("video")) {
          _imageFile = File(path!);
        }
        return;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is what shows in the console after i click on the image

[image: debug console]

And this is the galery after i clicked

[image: galery]

Comment: Could be an issue with the gallery app and which all folders it considers to check for new images.

Comment: how can i solve it? I tried change the emulator and it didn't change but when i click on an image it askes permisson to access photos and media in my phone so idk whats wrong